# android : face detection and comparison

Tags: android, opencv, face-detection, face-recognition

I have 100 peoples photos on server, each photo contain 1 person.

I want to develop an android app that can capture a photo with more than 50 peoples in group and then check from database server that how many peoples are missing in capture photo.

Please suggest me how can i achieve this? any library or help most appreciated.

Comment: You have already tagged OpenCV in your question, So I guess you are somewhat familiar with OpenCV, I would suggest you to go through: http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/facerec_tutorial.html for facial recognition.

Comment: @ZdaR i can recognize and detect the face from image, but i don't know how to compare detected face with server photos (each photo contain 1 person photo)?

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is called openCv (open source computer vision), you can check it out on google and read more about it.

You can now build your app around this

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV has libraries that support face recognition. You will have to train a face detector (Fisher or LBP) for the 100 people whose photos are on the server, and then feed the current photo to the recognizer.

[Here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/facerec_tutorial.html) is a link to OpenCV documentation with sample code.